# Writing dataframe to Azure Blob Storage using Databricks generates an empty file

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-databricks

On Databricks, I have a daily job running  which writes a data frame to a parquet file on Azure Blob Storage. It creates one file and one folder with the same name. However, the file created on the directory I set it to is empty, and there is a folder with the same name containing a parquet file with "random name" that stores the dataframe's content.

[image: empty_parquet_file]
[image: random_name_parquet_file]

I wanted the parquet file to be saved as the agg_DF.parquet, so that the file name stays constant, but agg_DF.parquet is empty right now. Instead, **it looks like I’ll need to go inside the folder and grab whatever file whose name ends with `.parquet` but I’d really appreciate any help on how to do this**. Or is there a better way to do it on Databricks, so that the agg_DF.parquet is not empty when it’s saved on Blob Storage.

Here’s the code I have on Databricks:

```
OUTPUT_PARQUET_FILENAME = 'agg_DF.parquet'
container_name = ‘xxxxx’
account_name = ‘yyyy’
output_path = f"wasbs://{container_name}@{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{OUTPUT_PARQUET_FILENAME}"

spark_DF = spark.createDataFrame(agg_df).repartition('blob_date')
spark_DF.write.parquet(output_path, mode="overwrite")
```

Answer (score 0):

The way Spark works is it splits a file in part files over executors to process it in distributed fashion parallelly. So you always get a part file in output while writing data whose name you cannot control and only the output folder name you can control

So overall the process you are following is what I would recommend that use repartition/coalesce (1) to put it in single file inside folder, get .parquet file from that folder move it using dbutils and delete the folder

Below is the code I use to perform same activity

```
df.coalesce(1).write.csv("/temp_path/","overwrite")
z=[ x.name for x in dbutils.fs.ls("/temp_path/") if x.name.endswith("csv")]
print(z)
if len(z)==1:
  print(z[0])
  dbutils.fs.mv("/temp_path/"+z[0],"/final_path/filename.parquet')
dbutils.fs.rm("/temp_path/",True)
```

Replace temp_path and final_path/filename.parquet